# Empty functions in dart

Tags: performance, flutter, dart

Hellow people, in terms of performance, let's say I have the following condition.

```
List A = [];
bool b = true;

// first option
b ? A.add(1): () => {};

// second option
if (b) {
    A.add(1)
}
```

Which of the two above is clean and performance unintensive.

Am thinking of the second option, but the first is clean and takes one line only...

Do empty functions pose computational expenses?

Comment: `if (b) A.add(1);` would also take just one line. or you can also just pass `null` after `:`

Comment: Oh, thanks for this comment, I didn;t know this,, if you could turn it to an answer I would upvote it...

Comment: @DarShan, took me some time to learn that null is also a statement, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy/paste this code in the [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true)
But even with 1,000,000 iterations, the difference is very minimal.
However, it's much easier to read `if (b) A.add(1)` rather than the first option

```dart
void function1() {
  final A = [];
  bool b = false; // b is false to make sure the empty function is executed

  // first option
  b ? A.add(1) : () => {};
}

void function2() {
  final A = [];
  bool b = false;
  if (b) {
    A.add(1);
  }
}

void main() {
  const iterations = 1000000;
  var start = DateTime.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    function1();
  }
  var end = DateTime.now();
  print(end.difference(start));

  start = DateTime.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    function2();
  }
  end = DateTime.now();
  print(end.difference(start));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `if (b) A.add(1);` would also take just one line.
Or you can also just pass null after `:` like: `condition ? returnSomething : null`